# Creating multiple process for the same exe in windows VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a requirement, I need to create multiple processes for the same exe.I know I can use createprocess(""myapp.exe,,,,,,,,,) function to create a single process and which will create a process with the name "myapp.exe" and run that exe also.

Now all i need is to create process for the same exe .lets say processes like "myapp1.exe" ,"myapp2.exe"..... and so on.

Please help me how to do this in VC++.

Thanks a lot

Comment: *Now all i need is to create process for the same exe .lets say processes like "myapp1.exe" ,"myapp2.exe"..... and so on.* Is it the same EXE, or different ones? Why can't you call `CreateProcess` more than once?

Comment: it is the same exe.If I call createprocess more than once it is creating process with the same namei.

Answer (score 1):

Processes don't have names. `CreateProcess("myapp.exe", ...)` doesn't create a process with the name "myapp.exe"". It creates an anonymous process, running myapp.exe.